# How do you read the metadata of an m4a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting, audio

Im trying to read the metadata on m4a files and I've tried both mutagen and eyed3, but to no avail since they don't use id3 tags.

I can't manually sort the 300+ songs i have downloaded and i want to develop my computer science skills and thought it would be fun to do.

stuff ive tried:
when trying to use mutagen it just comes up with:
`mutagen.id3._util.ID3NoHeaderError: 'D:\\songs\\<song>.m4a' doesn't start with an ID3 tag`
(the `<song>` was just to obscure the song, i did actually put a legitimate file name in there.
similar story with eyed3

there is a tool for editing m4a's but to no avail since it uses swift, which is code made by apple, meaning i would have to download a new ide to run it, plus it only edits the m4a files, rather than sort them.